# What should I flag as duplicate? New question or old question?

Tags: support, duplicates, best-practices

Someone asked this question: [Why linear displacement is length of the arc?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/653428/) which is similar to this question: [Confused about linear displacement in circular motion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/618522/). The second question has been published earlier. So when I tried to flag the new question as a duplicate, the old one didn't appear on the list becuase it has no upvoted or accepted answers. But the new question has upvoted answers. So what should be the duplicate one?

Comment: Related question on mother meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147643

Comment: There are arguments into both directions. You can flag both, and not always a bad idea to do it so. The first closed question will be the dupe. Nothing obliges us to click always the newer as dupe. Note: being a dupe is completely unrelated from their quality, and by flagging for closure you already understand both questions, with their answers, well. So do not forget to vote up (or down) the good ones. Obviously it is better if the better question becomes the orig (is already answered well, has a higher score/view count).

Comment: @peterh, the problem is that I am allowed to flag only one. Becuase (as I said before) one question will not appear in the list.